# My fixed vertical navigation bar is pushing my button down? How to fix it?

Tags: css, navigationbar

I have a problem with my fixed vertical navigation bar. By zooming out the page you will see that my sign up button will be pushed down. I tried everything to get it fixed but nothing worked for me. Does anyone know how to fix it??

I centered the text in the button, maybe that is why it is pushing the whole button down??

```
 text-align: center;
 vertical-align: middle;
 line-height: 40px;
```

[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/5y8vmno6/1/)

Comment: If you set the width of both login and signup to 49% it works on my screen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it's the border-right, that's causing the issue.
It will be more than 100% of the width for the browser if you add 49% + 50% button width + 1px border, but you can just use a box-shadow, since it's not affecting the box model:

```
#navigation #package .inloggen {
  width: 50%;
  box-shadow:inset -1px 0 0 gray
}
```

demo: https://jsfiddle.net/L2pdvays/3/

Answer (score 1):

Set box-sizing property to border-box for your divs. Those are getting pushed down because of the additional width of your borders. Border-box makes the total content, padding and border to be 49% instead of just the content and padding.

Basically the 3px border of the Login div is making the total to be 114px wide. That accounts for the 111px of content and padding PLUS the 3px of the border. The total of that div would then be 114px. If your other div is taking up 111px (since it has no borders)... 114 + 111 = 225px which is greater than your container width of 222px.

So to make 50% mean 50% of your TOTAL content + padding + border width, you need to set box-sizing to border-box. Doing so, you will be able to make both your divs 50%.